# Hidden Fields Lose Content on Postback

Tags: asp.net, session-state, forms

I am trying to create a session-less website in which I am using the StringBuilder to post the data to another form. The problem is that after the data is posted to the other form, the page loads correctly, but if I reload the page or hit the enter the hidden fields lose their values.

e.g

Page A is posting to page B using the StringBuilder, page B gets the form data and saves it in hidden fields, but now if I refresh the page everything is lost:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", "page2.aspx");
        sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='param1'  value='{0}'>", param1.Value);
        sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='param2'  value='{0}'>", param2.Value);

        sb.Append("</form>");
        sb.Append("</body>");
        sb.Append("</html>");

        Response.Write(sb.ToString());

        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain their values the hidden fields would need to be marked at `runat="server".` That would be me first appraoch - however I don't think this would work if you are constructing the form with a string (also the form would need to be `runat="server"`)

Actually looking at your code - you've circumvented webforms - so you are obviously not using them. So I would either use webforms as above or alternatively use an MVC approach with an appropriate model which will have the effect of maintaining state if doen correctly.

Alternatively the values could be picked up from the Request object on post back - bit old school though.